# IE9 crops text in input

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

I have a styled input. And this input can be "red" if something is wrong. Here is my snippet:

```css
.field {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: normal;
  outline: none;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  border-top-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  vertical-align: baseline;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 6px 8px 7px;
  margin: 0 !important;
  height: 32px;
  line-height: 17px;
  font-family: "Segoe UI", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.field.field-red {
  border-radius: 2px;
  border: 1px solid #d43517;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #d43517;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #d43517;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="field">
    <p />
    <input type="text" class="field field-red">
```

It is OK in all browsers except IE9. IE9 "crops" bottoms of letters (for example, q and g). What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Reduce padding from `field` `padding: 6px 8px 7px;` to `padding: 3px 8px 7px;` and increase from `height: 32px;` to `height: 35px;`

```css
.field {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: normal;
  outline: none;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  border-top-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  vertical-align: baseline;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 3px 8px 7px;
  margin: 0 !important;
  height: 35px;
  line-height: 17px;
  font-family: "Segoe UI", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.field.field-red {
  border-radius: 2px;
  border: 1px solid #d43517;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #d43517;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #d43517;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="field">
    <p />
    <input type="text" class="field field-red">
```

Comment: But this changes design and look.

Comment: you can adjust padding and height, just have to play with the padding n height values, I don't have the idea of the design but to prevent letters not crops, have to adjust the values, somewhere in between where don;t lose the design and issue get resolve too.

Comment: changes in these can resolve the issue without losing the design and look `padding: 6px 8px 7px;
  height: 32px;
  line-height: 17px;`

Comment: This is relly strange, because there are no problems in all other browsers, even IE8.

Comment: No its not strange as every browser has its own css rendering engine and ie-9 is kind of browser version which you can say experimental version because ie-10 has major updates more of which ie-9 doesnt has in initial launch version but later updates released by MS makes it worse.